# Can't connect to 3G using Sakis3G software

Tags: networking, usb-power, hub

I am trying to connect to a mobile network using the `ZTE MF190` USB dongle on my Raspberry Pi. I already successfully established the UMTS connection directly on the Pi's USB host, but later I added a powered USB hub and moved the UMTS dongle on to it. (I also make some modifications to my system later on). Now, the `lsusb` gives me this:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 057: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 061: ID 19d2:0117 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

Suddenly I **can not** make any connection using `Sakis3g`. `dmesg` gives me this:

```
[1396425.801185] usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 60 using dwc_otg
[1396425.903307] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=2000
[1396425.903336] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[1396425.903354] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
[1396425.903383] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[1396425.903400] usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: MF190***omitted***
[1396425.919933] scsi14 : usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.0
[1396428.124256] usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 60
[1396428.361269] usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 61 using dwc_otg
[1396428.463526] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=0117
[1396428.463555] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[1396428.463572] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
[1396428.463588] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[1396428.463618] usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: MF190***omitted***
[1396428.467838] option 1-1.2.1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[1396428.468389] usb 1-1.2.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[1396428.469150] option 1-1.2.1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[1396428.469723] usb 1-1.2.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[1396428.470497] option 1-1.2.1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[1396428.475264] usb 1-1.2.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

My `/etc/sakis3g.conf` looks like this:

```
APN=internet
APN_USER=<my_username>
APN_PASS=<my_pass>
USBDRIVER="option"
MODEM="OTHER"
OTHER="USBMODEM"
# This is my usbswitch mode for ZTE MF190:
USBMODEM="19d2:0117"
```

But when I run `sudo sakis3g connect -debug`, I get this on the end of the debug file:

```
 some debugging info, everything seems OK till here I guess:
 AT communication is OK, PDP context is getting established:

 AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
 OK    
  ....

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10171] [22:28:42] Will now run command: \'/bin/rm -f "/tmp/sakis3g.3gnet"\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10171] [22:28:42] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10171] [22:28:42] We are root already. Proceeding.
[10171] [22:28:42] Device /dev/ttyUSB2 is not busy.
[10171] [22:28:42] Verbosing: 42% Connecting
[10171] [22:28:43] PID 12827 is still running.
[10171] [22:28:43] Located "netstat" within PATH (/bin/netstat).
[10171] [22:28:43] Waiting for interface to go up (0 seconds passed).
[10171] [22:28:44] PID 12827 is still running.
[10171] [22:28:44] Interface ppp0 is up.
[10171] [22:28:44] Waiting for interface to go up (1 seconds passed).
[10171] [22:28:45] PID 12827 is still running.
[10171] [22:28:45] Interface ppp0 is up.
[10171] [22:28:45] Waiting for interface to go up (2 seconds passed).
[10171] [22:28:46] PID 12827 is still running.
[10171] [22:28:47] Interface ppp0 is up.

 ....
```

..till the script ends (after second connection attempt) resulting in **no GPRS/UMTS/HSDPA connectivity**.
I do not understand, why does my script on the one hand saying `Interface ppp0 is up.`, but on the other `Waiting for interface to go up (XX seconds passed).`?

My system is made of:

```
pi@pinew ~ $ uname -a
Linux pinew 3.6.11+ #456 PREEMPT Mon May 20 17:42:15 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@pinew ~/sakis3g $ ./sakis3g --version
Sakis 3G All-in-one script - Version 0.2.0e
(c) Sakis Dimopoulos 2009, 2010 under GNU GPL v2

pi@pinew ~ $ wvdial --version
WvDial 1.61
Copyright (c) 1997-2005 Net Integration Technologies, Inc.
```

I also tried:

**1)** With some other USB modem (`Huawei E220`), but the problem persists (*YES, I have changed the `sakis3g.conf` file*).

**2)** On another Raspberry Pi, (with `the same Raspbian version installed`), but the problem persists.

**3)** Another SIM card, (I replace the current `data SIM` with my personal phone's `SIM`), but the problem persists.

**4)** Changing the powered USB hub, (replacing `Genesys Logic` with `LogiLink 4x USB 2.0 powered hub`), but the problem persists.

**Is there anything else I have forgotten and is worth trying to establish with the UMTS connection and the USB dongle?**

Comment: Bounty not working, i guess :)

Comment: Can you send a message to Sakis support?

Comment: What happens when you run sudo wvdialconf I have a USB modem on a hub and sakis3g won't work for me either, but wvdial will with some simple configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I got my modem to connect after having this same issue. I used information from this forum [SparqEE](http://www.forum.sparqee.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=649&p=1058&hilit=sakis#p1058).

I installed minicom on my pi:

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

I then used minicom to connect to the modem:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

where ttyUSB0 was seen in the debug logs of sakis

in minicom "terminal" I typed the following command to "view" APN (I think)

```
at+cgdcont=?
```

followed by a command to set my apn:

```
at+cgdcont=1,"IP","internet"
```

where "internet" is my networks APN name.

I then exited minicom (press enter, ctrl+A(capital) followed by q)

I then reran sakis3g:

```
sudo sakis3g connect -debug
```

And I was connected!?!?!?